# How do I initialise Swagger Client for the browser with an auth token?

Tags: oauth-2.0, swagger, strava

In a browser-based (Cordova) app, I am trying to configure a swagger-client for the Strava REST API, to use an existing auth token in the request header.

Following the little guidance there is at 
 https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-js/blob/master/docs/MIGRATION_2_X.md I have come up with the following

```
    window.stravaClient = new SwaggerClient("https://developers.strava.com/swagger/swagger.json",
{ authorizations: { Authorization: 'Bearer '+ authToken }})
```

But, I keep getting the error:

*TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...).then( function() {...')*